# FTP an error occurred opening that folder on the FTP server

Tags: iis, ftp, connection, rdp

I have implemented filezilla ftp in my server correctly, however I cannot connect to it via windows 10. You can find the issue when trying to connect here https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0iVd.png

Additionally here is the server logs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmO5U.png

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling/enabling Use Passive FTP in Internet Options - Advanced

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Due to FileZilla [Network_Configuration](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration) you need to set up FileZilla Server with Windows Firewall. follow these steps:

1. Open Windows Firewall
2. Select `Allow an app or feature through Windows Firewall`
3. Click on `Allow another app...`
4. Click on `Browse...`
5. Locate the directory you installed FileZilla Server to (normally "C:\Program Files\FileZilla Server")
6. Double click or select "FileZilla server.exe" and press open
7. Scroll down the list and select "FileZilla server.exe" and click "Add".
8. Now you should return to previous window, verify that "FileZilla server.exe" is added to the allowed apps and features list and that it has a check mark in either the Private box or the Public box. Choose Private if you want the server accessible only from within your local network, and choose Public if you want the server accessible from outside your local network (this might include clients connected wirelessly to your network).
9. Press "Ok" to close the Windows Firewall window.
10. Open a command prompt with administrative rights and execute the following command: netsh advfirewall set global statefulftp disable.

It shall fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the file permissions. The root folder (usually the username) should have access to FTP with file read permission.

Comment: Yes, I have checked all of that and it still gives me the same issue. I have also selected the corect permissions in filezilla server

Comment: Too late for to ask but still wanted to know if the issue has been fixed.